# How to set up custom validation before an association is created in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Not sure if the question makes sense so I'll describe through an example:

Basically I have a company model in my app and a company employee. The employee is a devise model and can sign up/sign in. I have a wizard set up for the employee to select the company they work for after signing up, so the model accepts nested attributes for company.

During the stage where they select the company they work for, I want to set up a validation to ensure they only select the company they work for by matching the employee's email domain with the company's email domain in my db. At which point should i do this? Should I set up a custom validator or use a callback?

Here's my code:

Employee:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  ##################
  # Base
  ###################

  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :company_id, :company_attributes


  ##################
  # Associations
  ###################

  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
  has_many :authentications, dependent: :destroy

end
```

Company:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base


  ##################
  # Base
  ###################

  attr_accessible :name, :address_attributes, :email, :phone_number, :website, :confirmed



  ##################
  # Associations
  ###################

  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  has_many :employees


end
```

And here is the controller which is responsible for employees selecting a company, it's a wicked gem wizard controller.

```
class EmployeeStepsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_employee!
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :personal, :company_details, :enter_company_details

  def show
    @employee = current_employee
    case step
    when :enter_company_details
      if @employee.company
        skip_step
      else
        @employee.build_company.build_address
      end
    end
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @employee = current_employee
    @employee.attributes = params[:employee]
    render_wizard @employee
  end

  private

  def finish_wizard_path
    employee_url(@employee)
  end

end
```

I have another controller which deals with adding companies into the site separately for site admins but I only want to trigger the email validation in the wizard controller aka when employees are selecting their company. Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  ##################
  # Base
  ###################

  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :company_id, :company_attributes


  ##################
  # Associations
  ###################

  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
  has_many :authentications, dependent: :destroy

  # HERE
  validate :my_custom_vaildator

  private
    def my_custom_vaildator
      # do stuff .....
      # based off that stuff add errors
      if some_logic_about_your_company?
          self.errors.add(:base, "select the company you work for.")
      elsif some_other_logic?
          self.errors.add(:name, "your name sucks.")
      end
    end  
end
```

REMEMBER:

never return nil or false.  If you do it will go BANG!

=)

all this said the front end should never allow them to select something that isn't allowed.